# How to fix a weird Safari border css bug, where some parts of the borders don't show up?

Tags: css, safari, border

Parts of my borders aren't showing up in Safari!?

Check this out. It is very strange:

http://jsfiddle.net/myWqs/1/

(Make sure you're using Safari / Mac OS X)

Here is a screenshot, for those currently in a different browser:

[image]

And here are the details for you to reproduce (included because StackOverflow says "don't just link to jsfiddle").

HTML:

```
<h1>Example safari bug with the borders on the .holder divs</h1>
<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="column">
  <div class="holder">
    <h1>Stuff here</h1>
      <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12px;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 50%;
}

.holder {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e8e8e8), to(#f3f3f3));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e8e8e8, #f3f3f3);
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 18px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I tried it in Safari 6.0 on Mac OS 10.7.4 and it looks fine. Which version of Safari and Mac OS is this bug happening on?

Comment: Looks good in Safari on Mac for me too http://imgur.com/14gV16c

Comment: I am using Safari 6.0.2 and Mac OS 10.8.2, Retina display MacBook Pro if that matters

Comment: I am using exact same Safari an OSX, but no Retina display. Looks all good!